# Onsen UI + Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, mobile, onsen-ui

My question is simple, can I use [Onsen UI](http://onsenui.io/) with BackboneJS ?
has anyone tried?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As [they say](http://onsenui.io/guide/overview.html):

> Even though Onsen UI uses AngularJS to provide custom elements, it is not required to understand AngularJS. Onsen UI can be used with any JS frameworks including jQuery or Backbone.js, or with AngularJS to have a tighter integration.

Even I think that would be better using it just with `Angular`, I have successfully used it with `Backbone` and `Requirejs`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible.

```
...

<script src="js/underscore.js"></script> 
<script src="js/backbone.js"></script> 

<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>    
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>    
<script src="js/app.js"></script> 

...



var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);


myApp.controller("foo", function($scope) {

   var obj = new Backbone.Model();
   obj.set({name: "John"});
   obj.set({age: 20});

   console.log("obj: " + JSON.stringify(obj));
   console.log("obj.name: " + obj.get("name"));

});
```

However, I prefer the way to use only with AngularJS.